# Google Chrome has stopped working

Tags: google-chrome

Last night, I was using Chrome just nicely, but this morning, I can't even start Google Chrome as it immediately crashes. I have already tried a clean uninstall and reinstall of Google Chrome but still the same error pops up (it does not happen while I'm opening Google Chrome. I woke up and only then realized I can't open my Chrome and it keeps popping up saying that Google Chrome has stopped working.)

OS : Win 7 64-bit

Here is the detail of the crashes

```
Problem signature:

Problem Event Name:    APPCRASH  
Application Name:    chrome.exe   
Application Version:    35.0.1916.114 Application Timestamp:    53726019  

Fault Module Name:    chrome.dll  
Fault Module Version:    35.0.1916.114  
Fault Module Timestamp:    53725d18  

Exception Code:    c0000005   
Exception Offset:    00728bc8    

OS Version:    6.1.7600.2.0.0.768.3   
Locale ID:    17417  

Additional Information 1:    0a9e   
Additional Information 2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789   
Additional Information 3:    0a9e   
Additional Information 4:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Any help that will solve this problems is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Backup the profile folder, delete the profile folder, then open Chrome.

Comment: This question begs to be asked as you didn't provide this information: What happened between last night and this morning ? Did your machine get patched ? Did an automatic process updated your drivers ? Also what kind of machine/OS/version are you using ?

Comment: @Ramhound how do i do that? because previously i have uninstalled al pretty much deleted all the temp files in my laptop..but i could give your suggestion a try..just have to guide me through.

Comment: @Mel_Burslan i just left it overnight..and i dont really know what have happened between 4am to 9am..i think i got is ip conflict error.

what do you mean by patched? i am not sure if there is automatic process updated my driver

my machine is Lenovo G460
my OS is Win7-64bit
version of?

Comment: I am assuming you reboot this computer, at least to eliminate the chances of having a random memory leak or something. Right ? When your laptop was coming back up, did you see a screen telling you "do not power off, windows is updating" or something similar ?

Comment: no updates while i rebooting my machine. so yeah i did the uninstall thing twice and i kind of need to search for a better solution as the uninstall and reinstall the google chrome did not fix the problem

Comment: IP conflict error usually means, your machine gets its IP address from a DHCP and someone else (assuming you are on a crowded network) has "jimmied" your IP address as his or her static IP. But if you have reboot and not see that error again, you are in good shape on that end. Obviously something has changed on your system, with or without your knowledge. Best way to attack this program is to perform a system restore to the latest restore point before yesterday.

Comment: There are support articles that indicate the location of the Chrome user profile I would read them

Comment: @Mel_Burslan i tried to find system restore which dated yesterday.Which there is no programs have been modified till last night..so thats a bummers for now i will try clean boot method see if it would help me out with my problem

Comment: @Ramhound ty i will read them.

Comment: No matter what, try to do a system restore to the latest point prior to last night, regardless how old it looks.

Comment: @Mel_Burslan for trying helping me out here..i have already solved this problem using amberly13 methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the same experience. My Google Chrome was also working earlier today, and come night time, it was crashing every time I started it up. I uninstalled, deleted all Google Chrome folders (e.g., Program Files, AppData), reinstalled, did a reboot, but all to no avail.

What worked for me was to do a "clean boot". You can check it out here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135

Comment: i will try out your "clean boot" method and will get back to you either i failed or succeed

Comment: i wish i could vote up your trick because it worked for me..after many times of rebooting..i finally found the problem.. ty for the help amberly

Comment: You're welcome Axi. What is it that prevents you from upvoting?

Comment: required 15 reputation..which i only had 1.. >.<

Comment: This answer did not work for me. :(

Answer (score 4):

This answer is for those running **Comodo** Internet Security (Firewall).

In the Comodo control panel:

**Tasks**

[image: Tasks]

**Advanced Tasks**

[image: Advanced Tasks]

**Open Advanced Settings**

[image: Open Advanced Settings]

**Security Settings -> Defense+ -> HIPS -> HIPS Settings -> Detect shellcode injections [Exclusions]**

[image: Security Settings -> Defense+ -> HIPS -> HIPS Settings -> Detect shellcode injections]

**Add -> Files**

[image: Add -> Files]

**"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"**

[image: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"]

Be sure to click OK afterwards so that these settings are applied and saved!

[Source: sarjoor from Google Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/7WP_loNhIJs)

Comment: Thanks for a superb explanation, this fixed the problem for me (I'm using the Comodo Free Firewall only, but that includes HIPS).

Comment: Looks like this issue just started happening to most of us Comodo users. Glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks very much, same issue here, had me completely stumped.

Comment: Seems Comodo noticed too, Version 8.2.0.4703 has 'Compatibility with Google Chrome 45.x issue ' as the only change.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1) Windows Key + R (Run) and type `msconfig` OK

[image]

2) Click `Services` tab and disable all google update services.

[image]

3) Click Apply & OK. Then Select Restart from following dialog box.

[image]

4) After Restart chrome will work perfectly. You can re enable google update services by selecting check boxes in servrices tab.

Answer (score 0):

My chrome has come back after executing:

```
SFC.EXE /SCANNOW
```

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For those who were **unable to solve using other methods** provided, the final alternative is to install and use Chrome Canary (https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html). It seems to work where the regular chrome fails.