# Google Chrome is not opening

Tags: google-chrome

I just sign in to my PC and tried to open Google Chrome Browser which was perfectly working at last time BUT this time it didn't shows anything. I tried to open it as Administrator but still it shows nothing.

I m using Windows 8.1 OS.Google Chrome latest version is installed. The time I click the browser icon mouse cursor get hanged and then disappears and shows nothing.

Comment: We need more information if you want help.

Comment: @Ramhound Well do you need me to give my PC to you ?

Comment: Well Chrome is crashing.  So something on your PC is doing it.  Does it happen in Safe Mode.  I have about 15 different questions for you.  Won't be asking them since you have given so little information, it would take about 30 comments, to get the information I need to submit an answer.  I want to help but you have to give us more information to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i don't know exactly why does it happens, but when you try to run your Google Chrome as Administrator it opens after 5 minutes automatically.

> For more info take a look on this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/758001/google-chrome-has-stopped-working?rq=1)

Comment: Here it starts working after 10 minutes , by the way the link is very helpful.

Comment: There is nothing in your link regarding running Chrome as an Administrator ...